# Removing an item in an object's list and replacing it with another value/string

Tags: python, list, class, append

Working on a program that plans appointments with doctors I was trying to implement an option to edit an appointment. I want it to delete a specific item out of a list and replace it with a string.
Basically, a specialist is an object that has several attributes including a list called "spapplist" (specialist appointment list). I have created a function that prints the list and prompts the user to input what appointment he wants to edit. So if a user inputs a 2, it means that spapplist[2] will be removed. I got that working and ready but it gives me an error whenever I try to replace the appointment for a string with "No appointment"

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the code that causes it:

```
del self.spapplist[appointment_choice][1]
self.spapplist.append[appointment_choice]("No appointment")
```

The spapplist is a list of times like so:

```
spapplist = ["09:00 - 09:30","Appointment"],["09:30 - 10:00","Appointment], and so on.
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here or give me some advice?
I hope I have given enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index into the `spapplist` instead:

```
del self.spapplist[appointment_choice][1]
self.spapplist[appointment_choice].append("No appointment")
```

Your code is trying to apply indexing to the `.append()` method on the `self.spapplist` object  instead.

Instead of deleting index `1` and appending a new value, it be more efficient to just assign the new value to that index:

```
self.spapplist[appointment_choice][1] = "No appointment"
```